# Why does my M1 Mac not see my Network Printer/Scanner?

Tags: network, apple-silicon, scanning, image-capture

I have a Samsung SCX-4828FN network printer which on my older Intel Mac's are able to detect both as Printer and Scanner. When I open Image Capture, the scanner is dispalyed.

On my new M1 MBP however, while the printer is found on the network (and I'm able to print); I cannot see the device as a scanner in the Image Capture app.

Does anyone know why this is and how I could resolve?

Comment: Probably because the full set of drivers for the printer has not been downloaded -- it's probably just using Airprint to print.

Comment: Try here: https://www.samsung-driver.org/2020/02/samsung-scx-4828fn-driver-mac.html

Comment: I have tried this, it says the drivers are not supported when trying to install. I suspect it doesn't support Silicon CPU's.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help your situation or not but I had a Samsung SCX-4263. It broke printing and scanning when I bought my M1 Macboook air. I installed the Samsung Universal Printer and Scanner Driver (https://driverfresh.com/en/printers/samsung/3-universal-driver.html) and then selected Samsung M2060 driver. This one is the most common for abandoned Samsung/HP printers. It fixed both my printing and scanning. Hope this helps and post back here if it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I can’t find a first party scanner driver, my first stop has been VueScan for quite some time.

- https://www.hamrick.com/

The reason a device won’t show on recent OS typically the driver isn’t standard and/or Apple didn’t include it in updates or upgrades.